# React-Redux Javascript app - trying to get lots of API calls to fire in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, react-redux

I'm having an issue with successive API calls (using JQuery's AJAX) to two different APIs in order to build objects with certain attributes.  Here's the summary of my app and what I'm trying to do:

The user enters in the name of an actor or director, and the app is meant to return a total of five movies, each of which has certain attributes like title, overview, year, budget, revenue, and a link to a YouTube preview. I'm using The Movie Database API, plus the YouTube API for the YouTube link.

Here's the order of how things currently to work, with all of this happening in the action creator of the Redux app:

1. Actor name gets sent to the TMDB API -- returns ActorID number
2. ActorID number gets sent to the TMDB API -- returns 20 movies with: title, overview, year, poster link, and MovieID number
3. For EACH movie in that list, the MovieID number gets sent to the API -- returns more attributes: budget, revenue, and IMDB-ID (to use in a link later)
4. Also for EACH movie in step 2, the title gets sent to the YouTube API -- returns a link to the preview.

Once all of this information is assembled for each movie, I want to return the first five movies and dispatch them as the action payload to the Redux store.

I'm using some promises, and I've tried everything I could think of in terms of rearranging the flow of functions, but I can't get all the information I need with one click of the submit button.  The funny thing is, it works with TWO clicks of the submit button, I think because by then all the async AJAX calls are finally done.  But after the first click, I have an empty array where the movie objects should be.

Here's some code that should summarize what things look like:

```
var personId
var movies = []

function actorByRating(UserInput) {
```

Step 1: get actor ID number:

```
function searchActors() {
return $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?query=${UserInput}&api_key=<key>`
}).done(function(response){
  personId = response.results[0].id
})
}
```

Step 2: Use Actor ID to get list of movies, start assigning them attributes:

```
function getMovies() {
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?with_cast=${personId}&vote_count.gte=20&sort_by=vote_average.asc&budget.desc&api_key=<key>&include_image_language=en`
}).done(function(response) {
  response.results.forEach((m) => {
    var movie = {}
    movie.title = m.title
    movie.year = m.release_date.split("-")[0]
    movie.movieId = m.id
    movie.overview = m.overview
    movie.poster = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + m.poster_path

    getMovieInfo(movie) //step 3
    getYouTube(movie) //step 4
    saveMovie(movie)
  })
})
}
function saveMovie(movie){
  movies.push(movie)
}
```

Step 3 function, takes in a movie object as an argument:

```
function getMovieInfo(m){
  return $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${m.movieId}?&api_key=<key>&append_to_results=imdb_id`
  }).done(function(response) {
    m.revenue = response.revenue
    m.budget = response.budget
    m.imdbId = response.imdb_id
  })
}
```

Step 4 function, to get Youtube link.  Also takes a movie object:

```
function getYouTube(movie){
  $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=${movie.title.split(" ").join("+")}+trailer&key=<key>`
  }).done(function(yt){
    movie.youtubeLink = `http://www.youtube.com/embed/${yt.items[0].id.videoId}`
  })
}
```

After this, the filtering functions work fine, when they have an array of movies to work with.  The problem is, I think, all these successive API calls keep firing before the previous ones are done, and the latter ones need info from the earlier ones to search with.  Thus, when I click submit the first time, the final movies array is empty, so the dispatched payload is an empty array.  THEN the movie objects get filled in, so when you click submit again, the movies are already there to work with, and the rest of the app works fine.

I've tried everything I can think of to slow the process down, chain promises together (which doesn't work because Step 2 has to run for several movies, i.e. the return values of each function keep changing, so I can't ".then" them), reorganizing the information that comes in...but I can't get it to give me movie objects with all the attributes I need by the time the filtering functions actually run to create the proper payload.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

### (Note: the "key" stuff above is just placeholder text)

UPDATE:
I changed the code to basically the following:

```
searchActors()
.then(function(response){
const actorId = response.data.results[0].id
return actorId
})
.then((personID) => {
return getMoviesFromPersonID(personID)
})
.then(function(response) {
const movieList = []
response.data.results.forEach((m) => {
  var movie = {}
  movie.title = m.title
  movie.year = m.release_date.split("-")[0]
  movie.movieId = m.id
  movie.overview = m.overview
  movie.poster = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + m.poster_path
  movieList.push(movie)
  // saveMovie(movie)
})
return Promise.all(movieList)
})
.then((movieList) => {
const deepMovieList = []
movieList.forEach((movie) => {
  getMovieInfo(movie)
  .then(function(response) {
    movie.revenue = response.data.revenue
    movie.budget = response.data.budget
    movie.imdbId = response.data.imdb_id
    deepMovieList.push(movie)
  })
})
return Promise.all(deepMovieList)
})
.then((deepMovieList) => {
const finalMovies = []
deepMovieList.forEach((movie) => {
  finalMovies.push(getYouTube(movie))
})
return Promise.all(finalMovies)
})
```

Everything works fine right up until the first mention of "deepMovieList".  I can't seem to figure out how to have that particular step to work properly, as it essentially involves making 20 API calls with each movie in the movieList.  I can't figure out how to 1) get the info back from the API, 2) assign the attributes to the movie object that is passed in to getMovieInfo, and then 3) push that movie object (with the new attributes) to an array that I can use Promise.all on, all without interrupting the promise chain.

Either it moves on to the next "then" function too early (while deepMovieList is still an empty array), or, with other random stuff I've tried, the array ends up being undefined.

How can I have the next "then" function wait until 20 API calls have been made and each movie object has its updated attributes? This will also run into the same problem in the next step, for the YouTube link.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: use `fetch` and promises instead of jQuery, group promises using `Promise.all`.

**The Longer Version**

Ok, I'm not going to repeat all your code here. I'm going to abbreviate some stuff to keep it simple.

Basically, you have a bunch of tasks to perform. I'm going to pretend each of them is a function that returns a promise which is resolved with the data you want.

1. `searchActor()` - returns a promise resolved with some ID number
2. `getMoviesFromActorID(actorId)` - returns a promise that resolves with an array of movie IDs
3. `getMovie(movieId)` - returns a promise that resolves with the details for the given movie ID
4. `getYoutube(movie)` - returns a promise that resolves with the Youtube embed code.

Given this basic setup (and I admit I'm leaving out a lot of stuff), the code looks like this:

```
// search for an actor
searchActor('Brad Pitt')

// then get the movie IDs for that actor
.then((actorId) => getMoviesFromActorID(actorId))

// then iterate over the list of movie IDs & build an array of 
// promises. Use Promise.all to create a new Promise which is
// resolved when all are resolved
.then((movieIdList) => {
    const promiseList = [];
    movieIdList.forEach((id) => promiseList.push(getMovie(id)));

    return Promise.all(promiseList);
})

// then get Youtube links for each of the movies
.then((movieDetailsList) => {
    const youtubeList = [];
    movieDetailsList.forEach((movie) => youtubeList.push(getYoutube(movie)));

    return Promise.all(youtubeList);
})

// then do something with all the information you've collected
.then((finalResults) => {
    // do something interesting...
});
```

The key to this is `Promise.all` ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)), which will take an array of Promises (or any other iterable object containing promises) and create a new Promise which will resolve when all of the original promises have resolved. By using `Promise.all`, you can create a step in your promise chain which can include a variable number of parallel actions which must complete before the next step.

You *could* do something like this will jQuery and callbacks, but it would be pretty darn ugly. One of the great benefits of promises is the ability to lay out a series of steps like above.

Comment: Does the finalResults block only have access to the list of YT movies? What if you need the `promiseList` from the second block?

Comment: The way I've written it, yes, but that's mainly because I left out a lot of stuff. You could declare an object outside the promise chain and, at each step, add the info you're interest in to it. Then, when it's all done, you could use that object however you like.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks, (um...prepare for terrible pun...) promising.  I think the Promise.all is exactly what I need to have the rest of the process wait for the relevant information.  One thing: when the list of movie IDs is generated, that particular call also returns movie attributes that I need (just different ones from then searching via movie ID...very annoying feature of the API). Just to check, you're saying that if I make an object outside the promise chain, I should be able to push data to it at each step without it interrupting the promise chain? Thanks again!